# docker ssl port and server port mapping to allow ssl communications

Tags: ssl, docker

My play scala app runs on port 9000 of its docker container using ssl. This docker container port is mapped to port 6000 of its physical server.

```
 0.0.0.0:6000->9000/tcp
```

Do I need something special on the server to make its port 6000 be enabled for ssl also?

I also have a firewall that "protects" this server. Every time I try to call my app I get the error:

502 Bad Gateway.

Comment: Did you try opening it in your browser? If so, what happened?

Comment: I got an error. The problem is that there is a firewall that "protects" the server so I am trying to verify that the server is or not the "guilty" one to ask another person that can config the firewall to establish ssl com to this server through its port 6000

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the error?